# Can I find the position of applied generic arguments on a MethodInfo object?

Tags: c#, generics, f#, system.reflection

I need to find out where exactly generic parameters for a function are applied.
Let's assume I have the following function and type

```
type Box<'a, 'b> = Box of 'a * 'b
let iToS<'a, 'b> (b : Box<'a, 'b>) : Box<string, 'b> =
    let (Box (i,v)) = b 
    Box ((sprintf "%A" i), v)
```

and I have a function that gets a function and returns the corresponding MethodInfo object

```
let getMethodInfo f : MethodInfo = ...
let mi = getMethodInfo <@ f @>
//now query mi
```

Is there anyway to find out where the the generic paramters are applied? so that

```
let iToS<'a, 'b> (b : Box<'a, 'b>) : Box<string, 'b> =
          |   |            ^   ^                  ^
          |   |            |   |                  |
          -----------------    |                  |
              |                |                  |
              ------------------------------------
```

so given a generic function (and its associated MethodInfo object) and (potential generic) function parameters and (potential generic) return types,
Is there a way to find out if the **generic params** of the function are applied to the **function param type** and/or to the **function return type** if any of these is a generic type as well?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the .NET reflection to find out where generic parameters appear in the parameters and return types of a generic function.

For example, let's look at a wrapper for `Map.map`:

```
module Test =
  let func (m:Map<'k, 'a>) (f:'k -> 'a -> 'b) : Map<'k, 'b> = Map.map f m
```

For completeness, here is what you need to get the `MethodInfo` in F# Interactive:

```
open System.Reflection

let t = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes() |> Seq.find (fun t -> t.Name = "Test")
let mi = t.GetMethods() |> Seq.find (fun m -> m.Name = "func")
```

The method is generic and you can print the names of the generic parameters:

```
for a in mi.GetGenericArguments() do
  printfn " - %s" a.Name
```

The following recursive function will then format a type that may contain the generic parameter (it prints the name of generic parameters and it also supports `Map` and functions, but nothing else):

```
let rec formatType (typ:System.Type) = 
  if typ.IsGenericParameter then typ.Name
  else 
    let args = 
      if typ.IsGenericType then 
        typ.GetGenericArguments() 
        |> Seq.map formatType |> List.ofSeq
      else []
    match typ.Name, args with
    | "FSharpFunc`2", [t1; t2] -> sprintf "(%s -> %s)" t1 t2
    | "FSharpMap`2", [t1; t2] -> sprintf "Map<%s, %s>" t1 t2
    | _ -> failwith "Not supported"
```

If you then get all parameters & return type of the method:

```
[ for p in mi.GetParameters() do yield p.ParameterType
  yield mi.ReturnType ]
|> List.map formatType
|> String.concat " -> "
```

You get a result which is the type signature you'd see in F#:

```
val it:string = "Map<k, a> -> (k -> (a -> b)) -> Map<k, b>"
```

This signature contains all the generic parameters. This is a minimal example that does not match the names in the signature with the names of the generic parameters, but you can easily do that following this example (just check for types where `typ.IsGenericParameter` returns `true` and use their name to match them with the corresponding generic parameters elsewhere in the type).

Answer (score 0):

actually its pretty easy if you know that f# functions (that are represented as MethodInfo objects of static .NET methods) also have a method `GetGenericMethodDefinition`.
This seems to work like the `typedefof< >` operator in f# in such a way to one gets the generic definition of a MethodInfo object.
Given that that function is indeed a a generic function which can checked with `IsGenericMethodDefinition`.

Below a SignaturePrinter that does work with any generic function any kind of generic data type

```
type Box<'a, 'b> = Box of 'a * 'b
```

First few helpers

```
let getFn e =
    let rec name e =
        match e with
            | Call (x, mi, y) -> mi
            | Lambda (_, body) -> name body
            | _ -> failwith <| sprintf "not a function %A" e
    name e

let join sep (ss: string []) = String.Join(sep, ss)

let wrap sepB sepE s = sprintf "%s%s%s" sepB s sepE

let generics (ts:Type[]) = 
    if Array.length ts > 0 then
        ts
        |> Array.map (fun x -> x.Name)
        |> join ","
        |> wrap "<" ">"
    else ""

let genericDef (mi:MethodInfo) = mi.GetGenericMethodDefinition()
```

Then the signature printer using auto quotations

```
type SignaturePrinter = class end
    with
    static member Print ([<ReflectedDefinition>] f : Expr<'a -> 'b>) =
        let mi = getFn f |> genericDef
        let typeSig (t:Type) =
            let sanitizedName (n:string) = n.Split('`') |> Array.head
            [|sanitizedName t.Name; generics t.GenericTypeArguments|]
            |> join ""
        let fnParams (m:MethodInfo) = 
            m.GetParameters()
            |> Array.map (fun x -> typeSig x.ParameterType)
            |> join " -> "

        [|
            [|mi.Name; mi.GetGenericArguments() |> generics; " ::"|] |> join ""
            fnParams mi
            typeSig mi.ReturnType
        |]
        |> join " -> "
```

Some generic methods to test for

```
let iToS<'x, 'y> (b : Box<'x, 'y>) : Box<string, 'y> =
    let (Box (i,v)) = b 
    Box ((sprintf "%A" i), v)
let iToB (Box (i:int, v:'a)) = Box (i > 0, v)
let fixedRet (Box (i:int, v:'z)) = Box (true, false)
```

And the test code

```
let s1 = SignaturePrinter.Print iToS 
//iToS<x,y> :: -> Box<x,y> -> Box<String,y>
let s2 = SignaturePrinter.Print fixedRet
//fixedRet<z> :: -> Box<Int32,z> -> Box<Boolean,Boolean>
let s3 = SignaturePrinter.Print iToB
//iToB<a> :: -> Box<Int32,a> -> Box<Boolean,a>
```